# The AppNavigator is not exporting the required page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My `SplashScreen` page is not being exported by the AppNavigator even though the variable is declared and read, on the `SplashScreen` page.

I have tried to use createDrawerNavigator but I get the same result. I have tried to reset the cache with: 
`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
`npm start -- --reset-cache`

I have tried to reInstall the `createDrawerNavigator`

The error is below:

```
Unable to resolve module `./navigation/AppNavigator` from 
`/Users/jaseyacey/Desktop/beermeapp4/screens/Splash.Screen.js`: 
The module `./navigation/AppNavigator` could not be found from 
`/Users/jaseyacey/Desktop/beermeapp4/screens/Splash.Screen.js`. 
Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

The `SplashScreen` code is below:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import {Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { inject } from 'mobx-react';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

@inject("stores")
class SplashScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const {stores, navigation } = this.props;
        setTimeout(() => {
            navigation.navigate("Login")
        }, config.store.SplashTime )
    }
    render() {
        const { stores } = this.props
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <image style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}} source= {config.store.SplashImg}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: I think navigation is in the main directory. `import AppNavigator from '../navigation/AppNavigator';`Will you try this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add you Splash Screen into your App Navigator and there you will create an App Container with your navigation type (drawer navigation in this case) and export the App Navigator containing your splash Screen as your first screen of navigation.

I don't have a Splash Screen on my project yet, but you can see how I configured my App Navigation here: https://github.com/pahferreira/destetik-mobile/blob/master/src/navigation/AppNavigation.js

Or you can check here on their documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html